# Sqlite python sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, sqlite

I have written the following code, which is showing the `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked` error. Any help to debug would be much appreciated.

**Basically I am trying to copy data from  table1 to table2 and inserting data to table2 based on changes happening to table1 by some other application.**

Looks like I am missing some part.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/sid/.Skype/testmasterut/main.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

createLogTableSql = """create table IF NOT EXISTS sid_log as select id as "s_id",author as "s_author",timestamp as "s_timestamp",edited_by as "s_editedby",edited_timestamp as "s_edited_timestamp",body_xml as "s_body_xml" from Messages"""

cursor.execute(createLogTableSql)
conn.commit()
print "Table to save the old messages has been created"

selectLog = """ select * from sid_log """
original_table = cursor.execute(selectLog)

cursor2 = conn.cursor()
cursor3 = conn.cursor()
cursor4 = conn.cursor()

InsertTest = """ insert or ignore into sid_log (s_id,s_author,s_timestamp,s_editedby,s_edited_timestamp,s_body_xml)
select id,author,timestamp,edited_by,edited_timestamp,body_xml from Messages where id not in (select s_id from sid_log where s_id = id) and edited_by is NULL and edited_timestamp is NULL
"""

EditedTest = """ select * from Messages where id in (select s_id from sid_log where s_id = id) and edited_by is not NULL and edited_timestamp is not NULL"""
conn.close()

while True:
    conn2 = sqlite3.connect("/home/sid/.Skype/testmasterut/main.db",timeout=3)
    conn2.execute(InsertTest)

    print "Total number of rows changed:", conn.total_changes
    EditedTest2 = """ select * from Messages where id in (select s_id from sid_log where s_id = id) and edited_by is not NULL and edited_timestamp is not NULL"""
    edited_list = conn2.execute(EditedTest2)
    conn2.commit()
    conn2.close()
    # for row in edited_list:
    #   queryString = "SELECT * FROM sid_log WHERE s_id IN (%s)" % str(row[0])
    #   original_message = conn.execute(queryString)
    #   for org_row in original_message:
    #       print "Message edited from", org_row[5], "to", row[5]
```

**Edit**
Below is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try2.py", line 28, in <module>
    conn2.execute(InsertTest)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: Please show us the traceback. Without knowing which line raises this exception, it's much harder to debug the problem.

Comment: sqlite does not handle concurrency well ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: It doesn't handle it _efficiently_, but [it does handle it correctly](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5). Besides, if the OP really only has one connection to the same file at a time, that shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: Meanwhile, is this the only program that's using the database? Given the name, I suspect maybe your Skype app is writing to it at the same time. Maybe it's intentionally keeping the database locked to make sure it can't get confused by other programs screwing with its data in mid-run? What happens if you quit Skype?

Comment: @abarnert Yes Skype will write to the database,  may be it locks it. But can't I avoid?  Or create another database for my Logginf

Comment: @abarnert Traceback added

Comment: If Skype is deliberately locking the database so you can't write to it, then you basically can't write to it while Skype is running. Even if you could trick it, Skype is probably doing that for a reason, and you'd likely end up corrupting something.

Comment: And yes, creating another database for your logging should work. In fact, it sounds like a good idea on its own merits. Why are you trying to cram that into Skype's database in the first place?

Comment: This might be worth a read if you are working with SQLITE: http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Comment: @abarnert If I need to proceed with creating another database ( which I did), how to proceed. I guess I am messing up with connection, cursor, everything

Comment: @abarnert Experiments with Skype, Basically Skype allows users to Edit a message, just want to track them as when a message is edited, the previous value is gone. So I am doing little bit circus here :)

Comment: @Technopolice: To create another database, just pass a different filename to the `connect` method. That's it.

Comment: @abarnert I tried as shown here http://pastebin.com/bfYmebce Didnt not work

Comment: @DarthContinent You might be knowing this?

Comment: @Technopolice: Does "Didnt not work" mean it worked? Or that it didn't? If the latter, what happened? (As a side note, never use `%`-formatting or any other means to insert values into a SQL statement; use SQL parameters. Also, don't use a query to look up IDs and then loop doing a separate query for each ID; use a `JOIN` or a sub-`SELECT` for that.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone, but I figured out a solution to my own Locked Database problem.

I use PyCharm and found that several instances of the script I was working on were all running. This was usually due to errors in the code I was testing, but it stayed active (and therefore the connection to the db was still active). Close out of those (stop all the processes) and try again - it has worked every time for me!

If anyone knows a way to make it timeout after a little while, please comment this solution. I tried `cur.execute("PRAGMA busy_timeout = 30000")` (found from another thread on a similar question) but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

"Database is locked" means that some other connection has an active connection.

Use [PRAGMA busy_timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout) to wait some time for the other transaction to finish:

```
conn.execute("PRAGMA busy_timeout = 30000")   # 30 s
```

However, if that other application deliberately keeps an open transaction to keep the database locked, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: `execute()` is a method for cursors not for connections.

Comment: @NunoAndré Tell that to the [sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute).

Comment: I have said but he responded that: _Once you have a Connection, **you can create a Cursor object and call its execute() method** to perform SQL commands_

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but it was resolved when I used the following to close the concurrent connections.

```
conn.close()
```

So, if your program begins like this:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('pg_example.db', timeout=10)
c = conn.cursor()
```

Make sure that you're including the conn.close() after each SQL statement

```
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
conn.commit()
conn.close() #This is the one you need
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cursor2 = conn.cursor()
cursor3 = conn.cursor()
cursor4 = conn.cursor()
```

I think you have to close the connection which you have opened,may be the error is because of that cause you have opened multiple connections.

```
cursor2 = conn.cursor()
"""EDIT YOUR DATABASE USING CODE AND CLOSE THE CONNECTION"""
connection.close()

cursor3 = conn.cursor()
"""EDIT YOUR DATABASE USING CODE AND CLOSE THE CONNECTION"""
connection.close()

cursor4 = conn.cursor()
"""EDIT YOUR DATABASE USING CODE AND CLOSE THE CONNECTION"""
connection.close()
```